How can I merge two dataframes based on last date of each group?
These are my DataFrames:
import pandas as pd
df1 = pd.DataFrame(
    {
        'close': [100, 150, 200, 55, 69, 221, 2210, 111, 120, 140, 150, 170],
        'date': [
            '2024-01-01', '2024-01-02', '2024-01-03', '2024-01-04',
            '2024-01-05', '2024-01-06', '2024-01-07', '2024-01-08',
            '2024-01-09', '2024-01-10', '2024-01-11', '2024-01-12',
        ]

    }
)

df2 = pd.DataFrame(
    {
        'group': ['a', 'a', 'a', 'a', 'b', 'b', 'b', 'b'],
        'close': [100, 105, 112, 117, 55, 65, 221, 211],
        'date': [
            '2024-01-01', '2024-01-02', '2024-01-03', '2024-01-04',
            '2024-01-05', '2024-01-06', '2024-01-07', '2024-01-08'
        ],

        'extend': [
            '2024-01-09', '2024-01-09', '2024-01-09', '2024-01-09',
            '2024-01-11', '2024-01-11', '2024-01-11', '2024-01-11'
        ],

    }
)

And this is the expected output. I want to extend df2 for each group in group column:
  group  close        date          extend
0     a    100      2024-01-01      2024-01-09
1     a    105      2024-01-02      2024-01-09
2     a    112      2024-01-03      2024-01-09
3     a    117      2024-01-04      2024-01-09
4     a    69       2024-01-05      2024-01-09
5     a    221      2024-01-06      2024-01-09
6     a    2210     2024-01-07      2024-01-09
7     a    111      2024-01-08      2024-01-09
8     a    120      2024-01-09      2024-01-09

7     b     55      2024-01-05      2024-01-11
8     b     65      2024-01-06      2024-01-11
9     b    221      2024-01-07      2024-01-11
10    b    211      2024-01-08      2024-01-11
11    b    120      2024-01-09      2024-01-11
12    b    140      2024-01-10      2024-01-11
13    b    150      2024-01-11      2024-01-11

The logic is:
Each group in df2 has a fixed extend date. This is the basically the date that each group should be extended using df1.
For example for group a, The data should be extended from 2024-01-04 to 2024-01-09. The start point of extending is basically df2.date.iloc[-1] for each group and the end is the extend.
This is my attempt that didn't work:
import janitor
def func(df2, df1):
    df2['extend_start'] = df2.date.iloc[-1]
    df2['extend_start'] = pd.to_datetime(df2.extend_start)

    df3 = df2.conditional_join(
        df1,
        ('extend_start', 'date', '<'),
        ('extend', 'date', '>')
    )

    return df3

df1['date'] = pd.to_datetime(df1.date)
df2['extend'] = pd.to_datetime(df2.extend)

out = df2.groupby('group').apply(func, df1=df1)


You could add the missing dates with groupby.apply, then map the unknown dates:
# ensure datetime
df1['date'] = pd.to_datetime(df1['date'])
df2[['date', 'extend']] = df2[['date', 'extend']].apply(pd.to_datetime)

# fill missing dates
# map missing one with values of df1
out = (df2.set_index('date').groupby('group')
          .apply(lambda x: x.reindex(pd.date_range(min(x.index.min(), x['extend'].min()),
                                                   max(x.index.max(), x['extend'].max()),
                                                  )).rename_axis('date')
                            .drop(columns=['group'])
                            .assign(extend=lambda x: x['extend'].ffill(),)
                )
          .reset_index()
          .assign(close=lambda x: x['close'].fillna(x['date'].map(df1.set_index('date')['close'])))
      )

Output:
   group       date   close     extend
0      a 2024-01-01   100.0 2024-01-09
1      a 2024-01-02   105.0 2024-01-09
2      a 2024-01-03   112.0 2024-01-09
3      a 2024-01-04   117.0 2024-01-09
4      a 2024-01-05    69.0 2024-01-09
5      a 2024-01-06   221.0 2024-01-09
6      a 2024-01-07  2210.0 2024-01-09
7      a 2024-01-08   111.0 2024-01-09
8      a 2024-01-09   120.0 2024-01-09
9      b 2024-01-05    55.0 2024-01-11
10     b 2024-01-06    65.0 2024-01-11
11     b 2024-01-07   221.0 2024-01-11
12     b 2024-01-08   211.0 2024-01-11
13     b 2024-01-09   120.0 2024-01-11
14     b 2024-01-10   140.0 2024-01-11
15     b 2024-01-11   150.0 2024-01-11

Intermediate before the map step:
   group       date  close     extend
0      a 2024-01-01  100.0 2024-01-09
1      a 2024-01-02  105.0 2024-01-09
2      a 2024-01-03  112.0 2024-01-09
3      a 2024-01-04  117.0 2024-01-09
4      a 2024-01-05    NaN 2024-01-09
5      a 2024-01-06    NaN 2024-01-09
6      a 2024-01-07    NaN 2024-01-09
7      a 2024-01-08    NaN 2024-01-09
8      a 2024-01-09    NaN 2024-01-09
9      b 2024-01-05   55.0 2024-01-11
10     b 2024-01-06   65.0 2024-01-11
11     b 2024-01-07  221.0 2024-01-11
12     b 2024-01-08  211.0 2024-01-11
13     b 2024-01-09    NaN 2024-01-11
14     b 2024-01-10    NaN 2024-01-11
15     b 2024-01-11    NaN 2024-01-11


Thanks a lot. Is it OK to use out = out.merge(df1, on='date', how='left', suffixes=['', 'df_1']) instead of the last line? I have multiple columns in my original data to fill the missing values. I am more comfortable to use merge

@AmirX yes it is, but you'll have two columns, one with the original df2 values and one with the new ones from df1, if you want to mix them as in your example output y'oud have to use fillna or where anyway. You can think of map as a merge with a single column. In short, you can use a merge but map as I used here is doing the same with less steps.

Yes thanks a lot again. merge works fine with my data. I just wanna double check to see if there are some major downsides.

You can use this approach:
df1["date"] = pd.to_datetime(df1["date"])
df2[["date", "extend"]] = df2[["date", "extend"]].apply(pd.to_datetime)

out = df2.groupby("group", as_index=False).first().drop(columns="close")
out["date"] = out.apply(lambda row: pd.date_range(row["date"], row["extend"]), axis=1)
out = out.explode("date")

out = out.merge(df2[["date", "close"]], on="date", how="left")
out = out.merge(
    df1[["date", "close"]].rename(columns={"close": "close_extend"}),
    on="date",
    how="left",
)
out["close"] = out["close"].fillna(out["close_extend"]).astype(int)

   group       date     extend  close  close_extend
0      a 2024-01-01 2024-01-09    100           100
1      a 2024-01-02 2024-01-09    105           150
2      a 2024-01-03 2024-01-09    112           200
3      a 2024-01-04 2024-01-09    117            55
4      a 2024-01-05 2024-01-09     55            69
5      a 2024-01-06 2024-01-09     65           221
6      a 2024-01-07 2024-01-09    221          2210
7      a 2024-01-08 2024-01-09    211           111
8      a 2024-01-09 2024-01-09    120           120
9      b 2024-01-05 2024-01-11     55            69
10     b 2024-01-06 2024-01-11     65           221
11     b 2024-01-07 2024-01-11    221          2210
12     b 2024-01-08 2024-01-11    211           111
13     b 2024-01-09 2024-01-11    120           120
14     b 2024-01-10 2024-01-11    140           140
15     b 2024-01-11 2024-01-11    150           150


First, make sure your date columns are in datetime format.
Then, we need to identify the last date for each group in df2.
The code I suggest is:
import pandas as pd

# Sample DataFrames
df1 = pd.DataFrame({
    'close': [100, 150, 200, 55, 69, 221, 2210, 111, 120, 140, 150, 170],
    'date': [
        '2024-01-01', '2024-01-02', '2024-01-03', '2024-01-04',
        '2024-01-05', '2024-01-06', '2024-01-07', '2024-01-08',
        '2024-01-09', '2024-01-10', '2024-01-11', '2024-01-12',
    ]
})

df2 = pd.DataFrame({
    'group': ['a', 'a', 'a', 'a', 'b', 'b', 'b', 'b'],
    'close': [100, 105, 112, 117, 55, 65, 221, 211],
    'date': [
        '2024-01-01', '2024-01-02', '2024-01-03', '2024-01-04',
        '2024-01-05', '2024-01-06', '2024-01-07', '2024-01-08'
    ],
    'extend': [
        '2024-01-09', '2024-01-09', '2024-01-09', '2024-01-09',
        '2024-01-11', '2024-01-11', '2024-01-11', '2024-01-11'
    ],
})

# Convert date columns to datetime
df1['date'] = pd.to_datetime(df1['date'])
df2['date'] = pd.to_datetime(df2['date'])
df2['extend'] = pd.to_datetime(df2['extend'])

# Function to extend df2 with dates from df1
def extend_group(df1, df2_group):
    last_date = df2_group['date'].max()
    extend_date = df2_group['extend'].iloc[0]
    
    additional_rows = df1[(df1['date'] > last_date) & (df1['date'] <= extend_date)]
    additional_rows['group'] = df2_group['group'].iloc[0]
    additional_rows['extend'] = extend_date
    
    return pd.concat([df2_group, additional_rows], ignore_index=True)

# Apply the function to each group
result = pd.concat([extend_group(df1, group) for name, group in df2.groupby('group')], ignore_index=True)

Hope this helps.

A conditional_join is not required here as it blows up the rows, which is not what you want. You want to complete the df2 to get all the range of dates, then join back to df1 and fill in missing values:
# pip install pyjanitor
import pandas as pd
import janitor as jn

# ensure datetime
df1['date'] = pd.to_datetime(df1['date'])
df2[['date', 'extend']] = df2[['date', 'extend']].apply(pd.to_datetime)

# introduce all range of dates - this will expose implicit missing rows
dates = {'date': lambda df: pd.date_range(df.date.min(), df.extend.max())}

(df2
.complete(dates, by='group')
.merge(df1.rename(columns={'close':'close_'}),on='date')
.assign(extend = lambda df: df.extend.ffill(), 
        close = lambda df: df.close.fillna(df.close_).astype(int))
.iloc[:, :-1]
)
   group  close       date     extend
0      a    100 2024-01-01 2024-01-09
1      a    105 2024-01-02 2024-01-09
2      a    112 2024-01-03 2024-01-09
3      a    117 2024-01-04 2024-01-09
4      a     69 2024-01-05 2024-01-09
5      a    221 2024-01-06 2024-01-09
6      a   2210 2024-01-07 2024-01-09
7      a    111 2024-01-08 2024-01-09
8      a    120 2024-01-09 2024-01-09
9      b     55 2024-01-05 2024-01-11
10     b     65 2024-01-06 2024-01-11
11     b    221 2024-01-07 2024-01-11
12     b    211 2024-01-08 2024-01-11
13     b    120 2024-01-09 2024-01-11
14     b    140 2024-01-10 2024-01-11
15     b    150 2024-01-11 2024-01-11


import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

df1 = pd.DataFrame(
    {
        'close': [100, 150, 200, 55, 69, 221, 2210, 111, 120, 140, 150, 170],
        'date': [
            '2024-01-01', '2024-01-02', '2024-01-03', '2024-01-04',
            '2024-01-05', '2024-01-06', '2024-01-07', '2024-01-08',
            '2024-01-09', '2024-01-10', '2024-01-11', '2024-01-12',
        ]
    }
)

df2 = pd.DataFrame(
    {
        'group': ['a', 'a', 'a', 'a', 'b', 'b', 'b', 'b'],
        'close': [100, 105, 112, 117, 55, 65, 221, 211],
        'date': [
            '2024-01-01', '2024-01-02', '2024-01-03', '2024-01-04',
            '2024-01-05', '2024-01-06', '2024-01-07', '2024-01-08'
        ],
        'extend': [
            '2024-01-09', '2024-01-09', '2024-01-09', '2024-01-09',
            '2024-01-11', '2024-01-11', '2024-01-11', '2024-01-11'
        ]
    }
)

# Ensure datetime
df1['date'] = pd.to_datetime(df1['date'])
df2[['date', 'extend']] = df2[['date', 'extend']].apply(pd.to_datetime)

'''
df1 :
    close       date
0     100 2024-01-01
1     150 2024-01-02
2     200 2024-01-03
3      55 2024-01-04
4      69 2024-01-05
5     221 2024-01-06
6    2210 2024-01-07
7     111 2024-01-08
8     120 2024-01-09
9     140 2024-01-10
10    150 2024-01-11
11    170 2024-01-12

df2 :

  group  close       date     extend
0     a    100 2024-01-01 2024-01-09
1     a    105 2024-01-02 2024-01-09
2     a    112 2024-01-03 2024-01-09
3     a    117 2024-01-04 2024-01-09
4     b     55 2024-01-05 2024-01-11
5     b     65 2024-01-06 2024-01-11
6     b    221 2024-01-07 2024-01-11
7     b    211 2024-01-08 2024-01-11
'''
# Create a date range for each group in df2
df2_group_ranges = df2.groupby('group')\
.apply(lambda x: pd.date_range(start=x['date'].min(), end=x['extend'].max()),include_groups=False)
'''
df2_group_ranges :
group
a    DatetimeIndex(['2024-01-01', '2024-01-02', '20...
b    DatetimeIndex(['2024-01-05', '2024-01-06', '20...
'''
df2_group_ranges = df2_group_ranges.reset_index().explode(0).rename(columns={0: 'date'})
'''
df2_group_ranges :
  group       date
0     a 2024-01-01
0     a 2024-01-02
0     a 2024-01-03
0     a 2024-01-04
0     a 2024-01-05
0     a 2024-01-06
0     a 2024-01-07
0     a 2024-01-08
0     a 2024-01-09
1     b 2024-01-05
1     b 2024-01-06
1     b 2024-01-07
1     b 2024-01-08
1     b 2024-01-09
1     b 2024-01-10
1     b 2024-01-11
'''
# Merge with df2 to fill missing dates
df2_expanded = df2_group_ranges.merge(df2, on=['group', 'date'], how='left')
print(df2_expanded)
'''
   group       date  close     extend
0      a 2024-01-01  100.0 2024-01-09
1      a 2024-01-02  105.0 2024-01-09
2      a 2024-01-03  112.0 2024-01-09
3      a 2024-01-04  117.0 2024-01-09
4      a 2024-01-05    NaN        NaT
5      a 2024-01-06    NaN        NaT
6      a 2024-01-07    NaN        NaT
7      a 2024-01-08    NaN        NaT
8      a 2024-01-09    NaN        NaT
9      b 2024-01-05   55.0 2024-01-11
10     b 2024-01-06   65.0 2024-01-11
11     b 2024-01-07  221.0 2024-01-11
12     b 2024-01-08  211.0 2024-01-11
13     b 2024-01-09    NaN        NaT
14     b 2024-01-10    NaN        NaT
15     b 2024-01-11    NaN        NaT
'''
# Forward fill the 'extend' column
df2_expanded['extend'] = df2_expanded.groupby('group')['extend'].ffill()
print(df2_expanded)
'''
   group       date  close     extend
0      a 2024-01-01  100.0 2024-01-09
1      a 2024-01-02  105.0 2024-01-09
2      a 2024-01-03  112.0 2024-01-09
3      a 2024-01-04  117.0 2024-01-09
4      a 2024-01-05    NaN 2024-01-09
5      a 2024-01-06    NaN 2024-01-09
6      a 2024-01-07    NaN 2024-01-09
7      a 2024-01-08    NaN 2024-01-09
8      a 2024-01-09    NaN 2024-01-09
9      b 2024-01-05   55.0 2024-01-11
10     b 2024-01-06   65.0 2024-01-11
11     b 2024-01-07  221.0 2024-01-11
12     b 2024-01-08  211.0 2024-01-11
13     b 2024-01-09    NaN 2024-01-11
14     b 2024-01-10    NaN 2024-01-11
15     b 2024-01-11    NaN 2024-01-11
'''
# Map the 'close' values from df1
df2_expanded['close'] = df2_expanded['close']\
.combine_first(df2_expanded['date'].map(df1.set_index('date')['close']))

print(df2_expanded)
'''
   group       date   close     extend
0      a 2024-01-01   100.0 2024-01-09
1      a 2024-01-02   105.0 2024-01-09
2      a 2024-01-03   112.0 2024-01-09
3      a 2024-01-04   117.0 2024-01-09
4      a 2024-01-05    69.0 2024-01-09
5      a 2024-01-06   221.0 2024-01-09
6      a 2024-01-07  2210.0 2024-01-09
7      a 2024-01-08   111.0 2024-01-09
8      a 2024-01-09   120.0 2024-01-09
9      b 2024-01-05    55.0 2024-01-11
10     b 2024-01-06    65.0 2024-01-11
11     b 2024-01-07   221.0 2024-01-11
12     b 2024-01-08   211.0 2024-01-11
13     b 2024-01-09   120.0 2024-01-11
14     b 2024-01-10   140.0 2024-01-11
15     b 2024-01-11   150.0 2024-01-11
'''

